# CKEditor newbie needs some help getting going

Tags: ckeditor

I Downloaded and installed CKEditor. I made a file called Hello World like example and saved it on my web site. Now I want to change it so how do I get it in a CKEditor window make some changes and save it back to the original file?

I've been reading and reading and don't see simple instructions. I see the example Hello World which comes up when I run the index.html file in Samples directory. I was able to make some changes to the Sample index.html, but how do I save it, there is no Submit button? There is something about this CKEditor I am not getting.

I just want to be able to change a section of a web page and save it without using Notepad++, then uploading it to server. And I don't want any users to be able to do it, just me. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. I have to write a special script to get the data, edit it and then put it back to the database? I can do that without CKEditor, so why do I need it then? 

Supposed I don't care about the formatting, I just want to put 'Hello World , it's sunny today' or 'it's raining today', without downloading the file, editing it offline and then uploading it to server. CKEditor can't do that?

Comment: Because CKEditor apparently is not the tool that you are really looking for. You say: "I can do that without CKEditor, so why do I need it then?" - and that's exactly the point. CKEditor replaces a different part of your setup (it's a WYSIWYG editor that lets you create/format your content with a toolbar instead of needing to write the same in plain HTML in a textarea), the rest is exactly the same as you would need without CKEditor. So, as @Atzmon suggested, you need to create this part by yourself anyway, just like you'd need to do it without using CKEditor at all.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor is not a full Content Management System, just a rich text editor (and a good one at that). You need to use its output, basically the contents of the textarea, and store it in your database or file system. What you do with the resulting HTML and how you do it depends on your specific system and platform (PHP, Ruby, ASP.NET etc).

Comment: How do I save the output? I made some changes on example. There is no submit button on the example. It lets me change text but then what, am I supposed to just wish it to submit itself? 

Horrible documentation for beginners. Maybe they don't want more people using it so they make it difficult to learn?

Comment: You need to implement your own save operation on your own server application, CKEditor cannot do that for you. The documentation is quite clear about that, and also provides basic examples: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata

Comment: Ok, I give up. The example gives me a Hello World. I change it and then what? What good is an example if it doesn't do anything. I gotten a million scripts and when they give an example, they work.I installed CKEditor on my server. I brought up the HELLO WORLD example. I changed it. Then I stare at it and wonder how to save the changes. It's on my server so I should be able to save it. What kind of a stupid example is that?

Comment: CKEditor is a client side library. It can only provide you with the data created on the client. What you do with that data is up to you, your server platform, your development language etc. CKEditor cannot do anything on the server side for you. Please note I'm not related in any way to the CKEditor product or team. I've used it and found it to be a very good editor for my needs.

Comment: It doesn't edit anything. Well yes it does, but it doesn't let me save the editing. When I reload the page, the changes are gone. There is no submit button. Why don't they give a useful example that shows the changes that were made when I reload the page.

The example sucks. I used tinyMCE before and was able to see changes right away. It's a horrible example by people who forgot that there are newbies that don't know all the crap they do.

And I do know you aren't connected with CKEditor and appreciate you trying to use your experience to help others. I am just frustrated at this.